# How to compute the cosine similarity between a 3D-tensor and a vector?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, torch

I want to calculate the cosine-similarity between a 3D tensor `x`:

```
torch.Size([119, 768, 51])
```

and the vector `y`

```
torch.Size([768])
```

This should of course result in this 2D Matrix:

```
torch.Size([119, 51])
```

Using `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity` gives me the error:

```
*** ValueError: Found array with dim 3. check_pairwise_arrays expected <= 2.
```

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do a transpose and reshape to obtain a tensor of size

```py
torch.Size([119*51, 768])
```

Secondly, expand the first dimension of `y`

```py
torch.Size([1, 768])
```

Finally, compute similarity then reshape results to expected size:

```py
torch.Size([119*51, 1])
torch.Size([119, 51])
```